# randomly select from dictionary of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined dictionary of dictionary of the form:

```
my_dict = {
    "my_key1": {"key_1": value_1, "key_2": value_2},
    "my_key2": {"key_1": value_1, "key_2": value_2, "key_3": value_3},
    "my_key3": {"key_1": value_1, "key_2": value_2, "key_3": value_3, , "key_4": value_4},
    "my_key4": {"key_1": value_1, "key_2": value_2}
}
```

I want to **randomly** select one "value" for each my_key.
I tried below which didn't work:

```
for key in my_dict:
    # randomly select from the sub-dictionary
        rand = random.sample(list(param[key]), 1)
    # get value at that randomVal
        net[key] = param[key][rand]
```

Is there any other way to randomly select the values for each key.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need `net[key] = param[key][rand[0]]` since sample returns list, you need `rand[0]` but what is `param`? did you mean `my_dict` instead?

Comment: yes, param was mistprinted for "my_dict". Thanks, the same worked :)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `list comprehension` and `random.choice`

```
>>> r = [random.choice(list(v.values())) for k,v in my_dict.items()]
['value_2', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4'] # example
```